# Definite/indefinite article when we talk about something that is known to some people only

Tags: articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

We use the definite article for things that were already introduced to a reader or the ones already familiar to everyone.

> A have a car. The car is red.
>
> The Sun is yellow.

But what about things that we assume to be known to the target audience?

For example, the style guide for some programming language may contain the following passage:

> #### Rule 17.
>
> To make *the(?)* operator precedence order more obvious, use additional parentheses.
>
> ```
> // Do
> if (x + (y * z) > 25) {
>    ...
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> // Don't
> if (x + y * z > 25) {
>     ...
> }
> ```

It is assumed that the programmer is not total newbie, and hence he/she should know what "operator precedence order" is. Hence, I use "the" and not "an". Is it correct?

Comment: The definite article is not just for 'things known to the reader', but also for 'particular ones'. In your example, _the_ operator precedence order _which applies to this particular programming language_.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you for pointing that out. But here is another example: "An assignment operator assigns a value to its left operand based on the value of its right operand." ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)). The article talks about an assignment operator which applies to JavaScript, but it doesn't use "the". Isn't it contradict what you said?

Comment: @john c. j. that sentence clearly implies that there is more than one possible assignment operator. And in some sense there is; aren't = and := and ← all assignment operators in various programming languages?

Comment: @john c.j. In fact, if you look further on the page you link to, it says "The basic assignment operator is equal (=), which assigns the value of its right operand to its left operand. That is, x = y assigns the value of y to x. The other assignment operators are usually shorthand for standard operations, as shown in the following definitions and examples."

Comment: If you were to use *an*, it would imply more than one possible operator precedence order, which would make no sense. @KateBunting nailed it.

Comment: @PeterShor and Richard Kayser, now thing are much clearer. Peter, I suppose you mean `<-` in R language :)

Comment: John, the link which you provide seems to be a definition of the phrase _assignment operator_, so what it says (at the top) applies to any one. It then gives an example relating to Java Script.

Comment: @KateBunting: but in some sense there is only one (logical) assignment operator: it's the operator that takes one thing and makes another thing equal to it; I assume that this is why the OP was confused by the word "an".  But Java has other things called "assignment operators" (and which the definition is careful to include, although a pedant might say they aren't really assignment operators) that do an arithmetical operation followed by an assignment.

Comment: @PeterShor I confess I know nothing about computer programming.